# "tail -f" show old file after file has been rotated

Tags: files, tail, logrotate

I have a script running continuously, reading `tail -f /var/log/daemon.log`

The problem is, when the file `/var/log/daemon.log` gets rotated by `logrotate`, tail still has "file handle" for the old (rotated) file and no longer displays the contents of the new `/var/log/daemon.log` file

Is there any way to fix this, so that `tail` shows the contents of the new file, if the file was rotated ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. You're looking for `tail -F` instead of `tail -f` (that is, a capital F instead of lowercase). Check the tail(1) manpage.

Alternatively, you could use `--follow=name --retry`, which the man page documents as the same thing.

(These are from GNU coreutils tail. Other tails may not have this; POSIX does not specify `-F`, `--follow`, or `--retry`. If you have to work on those systems, I'd suggest Perl's [File::Tail](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Tail).)